# twilio test credentials do not work for sending sms‏ - throws exception "Resource not accessible with Test Account Credentials"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms, twilio

I am building a ruby application for sending sms messages and I'm using the twilio gem. I'm following example 1 for test sending an sms in the documentation.

Example on Twilio site:

```
# Get your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = 'ACb62e32327e8ec258781341a039e65c46'
auth_token = '{{ auth_token }}'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

sms = @client.account.sms.messages.create(:body => "All in the game, yo",
    :to => "+14108675309",
    :from => "+15005550006")
puts sms.body
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-sms-messages

Here is what my code looks like

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['twilio_account_sid'], ENV['twilio_auth_token'])

response = client.account.sms.messages.create({ 
:from => '+15005550006',
:to => '<<a valid number>>', 
:body => "Some message" 
})
```

When I send to a valid number with my test credentials and this valid test from number (15005550006) I get an exception saying

"Resource not accessible with Test Account Credentials"

I don't see what I'm doing differently than the example.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using TEST account, you MUST use one of the predefined `to` numbers like shown here: [Twilio Doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-sms-messages-parameters-To)

If you use a real number, you'll get the error you see.

Comment: I don't think thats it. The example says `"Successfully send an SMS. Trigger this by sending an SMS using the magic number +15005550006 as the From number, and a regular phone number for the To number."` And the example uses a regular number "14108675309", but a predefines `to` number

Comment: You're definitely right but, just for test purposes, what happens when you use one of the predefined numbers?

Comment: There isn't a valid `to` number for testing. All of the `to` numbers they provide are for testing errors. The only valid number is the from number `5005550006` and if I use that I get the same message `"Resource not accessible with Test Account Credentials`

Comment: 1. Which version of the gem do you have?
2. Can you see the HTTP call that the gem does? (log or whatever)

Comment: 3.13.1 and no, I can't see the HTTP call

Comment: I just updarted the gem to the latest version and still get the same results

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going on here. My advice is to test the API through an external client (HttpMonkey, Faraday or HttpClient) and see if it works. In that case, the problem is from the gem, otherwise are their API...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that an let you know

Comment: I just tried it out in Postman and I don't get any errors. It seems to be a problem with the gem

Comment: Yes, definitely. Sorry I can't help more than this :(

Comment: It's ok, you get an upvote for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have a GET request after your POST to send the sms.

I was getting the same error and after I removed the get request

```
$message = $client->account->messages->get($sms->sid);
```

and now it is working well. (Test Credentials will work only with POST requests)

Answer (score 0):

With the PHP SDK (not sure about others), this message results if an attempt is made to access the `error_code` or `error_message` properties of Twilio's response while using test credentials.

A simple solution is to wrap any attempt to access these values in conditional logic (pseudo-code):

```
if (env('TWILIO_SID') !== 'AC2593237dd083dcde0480771b908f9de2') {
    //NOT using test credentials. Safe to access properties.
}
else {
    //Using test credentials. Accessing properties throws exception.
}
```